# Number of spanning trees of this graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

The solution to the number of spanning trees of the graph below is given by $3 \times 2 \times 3 = 18$. I'm not sure how to get this. Please assist. Thanks!

[image]

Notes:
Just in case anyone was wondering, I drew the graph using the tool on http://illuminations.nctm.org/Activity.aspx?id=3550 and got the image by using the snipping tool on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any spanning tree in the graph must contain exactly one CD edge, and this edge can be chosen in two ways.  For the subgraph to be connected, C must be in the same component as A and B.  Thus two of the three edges in the triangle ABC need to be included, and these two edges can be chosen in 3 ways.  Similarly the two edges in the triangle CEF can be chosen in 3 ways.  Thus the number of spanning trees is $2 \times 3 \times 3 =18$.